# Homology of $X/\{x\sim f(x)\}$ where $f\colon X\to X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a space and $f\colon X\to X$ a continuous map.
What tools do we have to compute the homology $H_n(X/\sim)$ where $\sim$ is defined by $x\sim f(x)$?

Relative homology was my first though, but beyond thinking of the words 'relative homology' I didn't get very far with that.

Comment: Your map $f$ defines a monoid action of $\mathbb{N}$ on $X$ (by $n \cdot x = f(f(\dots f(x)\dots))$, $n$ times $f$), and $X/\sim$ is the coinvariants of this action. In general there's no nice thing to say about the actual coinvariants... Taking quotients can do crazy stuff to homotopy type. If it were the *homotopy* coinvariants things would be a bit better. To convince yourself, look at what $X/\sim$ is when $X = S^1$ and $f(x) = e^{2i \pi \alpha} x$ for some irrational $\alpha$.

Comment: This is a step in an exam question that I'm trying to solve, but I've arrived at this step myself, so it's more likely than not to be wrong then. As a tangential question (to explain my derivation) when we look at an open subset $U$ of the mapping torus $T_f=(X\times[0,1])/\{(x,0)\sim(f(x),1)\}$ that contains $X\times\{0\}$ then I said that $U\simeq X/\{x\sim f(x)\}$ is a homotopy equivalence, and so $H_n(U)\cong H_n(X/\{x\sim f(x)\})$. This could be wrong though.

Comment: if you do not have more information of what $f$ does to $X$ then $H_*(U)$ could be anything like @NajibIdrissi says.